# Why isn't `length` generic by default?

Tags: haskell

Haskell often provides two versions of a given function f, i.e:

```
f :: Int ...
genericF :: Integral i => i ...
```

There exist many standard library functions with those two versions: length, take, drop, etc.

Quoting the description of `genericLength`:

> The genericLength function is an overloaded version of length. In particular, instead of returning an Int, it returns any type which is an instance of Num. It is, however, less efficient than length.

My question is: where does the efficiency loss comes from? Can't the compiler detect that we are using `genericLength` as an Int and therefore us `length` for better performance? Why isn't `length` generic by default?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262875

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same reason as why we have `map` and `fmap`. Error messages/usability for newbies.

It'd by mighty confusing for many a new programmer to write

```
myLength = subtract 1 . genericLength

x = myLength [1, 2, 3] :: Int
y = myLength [1, 2, 3] :: Integer
```

and get an error complaining about the monomorphism restriction. Plus which do you prefer

```
Couldn't match expected type "Integer" with type "Bool"
```

or

```
No instance for Num Bool arising from usage ....
```

It's simply a matter of usability.

Furthermore, in a lot of cases you end up just wanting defaulting anyways, such as with function composition

```
evenElems = even . subtract 1 . genericLength
```

vs

```
default ()
evenElems = even . genericLength -- Error ambiguous type variable.
```

Here we just want GHC to "pick" a random `Num` type and we really don't care which (it's `Integer` IIRC).

If everything was fully generic the defaulting rules would get um.. murky. Since  As of right now there are only 4 things that are automatically available as defaults and no way to set anything fine grained (per function).

As for efficiency, typeclasses means lugging potentially lugging typeclass's dictionary and defaulting to `Integer` which is much more expensive than `Int`.

There are alternative preludes (I think classy prelude is unmaintained, but interesting) that do attempt to be as generic as possible. Using them is as simple as

```
 {- LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
 import My.Super.Awesome.Prelude
```

Comment: "As for efficiency, typeclasses means lugging potentially lugging typeclass's dictionary and defaulting to Integer which is much more expensive than Int." Perhaps you might want to explain why the compiler cannot simply replace the generic code with the concrete version. A human can do it, so why couldn't (or shouldn't) a compiler not do this as well? Doesn't GHC have a SPECIALIZE pragma just for this? If so, why is this pragma needed instead of inferred?

Comment: What happens if the code is called with dozens or hundreds of types? It can be a source of unnaceptable code bloat if you keep specializing

Comment: @ThomasEding GHC does attempt to optimize and specialize where possible, but it isn't guaranteed to IIRC. See classes jim but not as we know them by spjThe bigger problem is the the default Integer

Answer (score 4):

Aside from usability, the reason seems to indeed be to avoid performance degradation. In the recent [Foldable in GHC7.10 Prelude's FAQ](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Prelude710/FTP#SimilarlythingslikelengthcouldbegeneralizedtoNummakinglengthandgenericLengthequivalent.)

> `length` is left ungeneralized with regards to the numeric type primarily because `genericLength` has absolutely abysmal performance. One of the pragmatic guidelines we followed is that we can't make code slower.

By looking at the implementation:

[length](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-List.html#length)

```
{-# NOINLINE [1] length #-}
length                  :: [a] -> Int
length l                =  lenAcc l 0#

lenAcc :: [a] -> Int# -> Int
lenAcc []     a# = I# a#
lenAcc (_:xs) a# = lenAcc xs (a# +# 1#)
```

[genericLength](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Data-List.html#genericLength)

```
genericLength           :: (Num i) => [a] -> i
{-# NOINLINE [1] genericLength #-}
genericLength []        =  0
genericLength (_:l)     =  1 + genericLength l
```

`length` has a tail-recursive implementation, and the helper function `lenAcc` can probably be inlined. This might explain the difference, but I'm not sure if there's more to it.

Comment: Is there not a way to define optimized genericLength implementations for each concrete type? (And then if the concrete type that is used is not one in that set then just use the general, slow, implementation.) Then when the compiler knows what type it wants to use, it could switch it out for that.

Comment: RULES can probably be used for this, but I'm not sure if specializing on the return type might be an issue... a couple of relevant SE links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745038/ghc-rewrite-rule-specialising-a-function-for-a-type-class http://stackoverflow.com/a/10535043/293735

Comment: @beradrio it seems like the problem that was encountered in the first link was due to typeclasses right? So return type as long as its a concrete type should work ok?

Comment: Yes, I just linked them because they are relevant to understand RULES used for specialization (the manual deals has only a small example, with no further discussion)